# How to upload useState and submit it to Firestore using single click

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

```
const favAnime = async (anime) => {
        setFavani(anime.title)
        setImg(anime.image_url)
        setScore(anime.score)
        setEpisodes(anime.episodes)
        setSynopsis(anime.synopsis)
        setUrl(anime.url)

      const addAnime= await addDoc(collection(db,"Users", uid,"fav"),{
        favani,img,score,episodes,synopsis,url
      })
  }
```

When I submit, the states updates but firebase receives empty state
value, I did add the if function to upload to firebase only when state
is not empty but it ended up submitting data of previous click

```
<div className={styles.grid}>
      {data.map(function(anime){  
        if(data){
        
      return <div className={styles.card}>
          <img src={anime.image_url}/>
        <div className={styles.wrap}>
          <h1>{anime.title}</h1>
          <p>Score: {anime.score}</p>
          <button onClick={()=>{favAnime(anime)}}>add</button>
        </div>
        </div>}})}
    </div>
```

Comment: This is because your setStates are not synchronous in nature [Refer this link](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html#why-is-setstate-giving-me-the-wrong-value). What you can do is set the states individually if you are getting the anime object tied up to any input. And then on submit, you can call this function directly and not set the individual states.

Comment: I updated the code, unfortunately, I have other component with input update onChange, but it is not the case here

Comment: Okay, got it. Then why don't you just try to pass the anime object to the firesbase instead of accessing the state variables?

Comment: The return has fetched 10 cards of anime with information as title etc, and it has button add, which indicates which one of those cards I want to add. Also all anime cards fetched are from API. Basically parent component has a search function which brings back 10 anime from API sorted by title, then it is displayed in this component and maps over 10 anime from API. I want to log the data of a single selected card and add it to firestore. This code is bringing back correct card but fails to submit at the same time

Comment: Yes, I got that. You then need a functionality where user can add particular anime as their favourite. Isn't this your `favAnime` method is doing?

Comment: Yes it is correct, my idea is to log the card details add to firebase and read from firebase in different page which would be favourite anime

Comment: You can refer the answer that is posted. The second approach would be better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just add Promise of a timeout to wait until your state updates.
modify your function like this

```js
const favAnime = async (anime) => {
        setFavani(anime.title)
        setImg(anime.image_url)
        setScore(anime.score)
        setEpisodes(anime.episodes)
        setSynopsis(anime.synopsis)
        setUrl(anime.url)

      await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 500))

      const addAnime= await addDoc(collection(db,"Users", uid,"fav"),{
        favani,img,score,episodes,synopsis,url
      })
  }
```

or you can use data directly from `anime` parameter

```js
const favAnime = async (anime) => {
  setFavani(anime.title);
  setImg(anime.image_url);
  setScore(anime.score);
  setEpisodes(anime.episodes);
  setSynopsis(anime.synopsis);
  setUrl(anime.url);

  const addAnime = await addDoc(collection(db, 'Users', uid, 'fav'), {
    favani: anime.title,
    img: anime.image_url,
    score: anime.score,
    episodes: anime.episodes,
    synopsis: anime.synopsis,
    url: anime.url
  });
};
```

Comment: time out did not work but the second part did, thank you